# How to show any finite-dimensional vector space can be given an inner product?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

My question is: how to prove any finite-dimensional vector space can be given an inner product?

I have been stuck in it for two hours. Could any one give me any hint?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Finite dimensional vector space over what field?

Comment: Thanks! It should be any field.

Comment: Inner products usually are only defined over the fields of real or complex numbers.

Comment: Hmm are you sure about any field? I may be wrong, but I think fields without characteristic zero may pose issues.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is exactly the question. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353252/true-or-false-every-finite-dimensional-vector-space-can-made-into-an-inner-prod

Comment: What is your definition of "inner product space" over an arbitrary field?